# Extract values from json string using Regex

Tags: json, regex, http, jmeter, jsr223

I get below response from one HTTP web request. and I wants to save value of ConnectionToken, ConnectionId values in separate variables using single Regular Expression Extractor post processor in jmeter.

Is there any way or alternative to do so?

```
{"Url":"/Administration/signalr","ConnectionToken":"/75qb328dXVeojvZYoX34bkWCnji55Zp5+eGEMbas4q0+qdcLNwTRMGHjZVwXgKIgixUc0sxhF659A6ttgg3xPkGOXQquii1sOscozYeEaBpcMmVFPQkeKnxwTf2Yjp007gbag==","ConnectionId":"1dc235ed-6f1f-41eb-bdfd-d0b8625aead6","KeepAliveTimeout":4.0,"DisconnectTimeout":6.0,"ConnectionTimeout":110.0,"TryWebSockets":true,"ProtocolVersion":"1.5","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0,"LongPollDelay":0.0}
```

Comment: use `m/"ConnectionToken":"(.*?)",/g`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions in order to extract values from [JSON](http://json.org/) data as it is well structured hence can be parsed faster and way more reliable using i.e. [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) which allows fetching "interesting" values via [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries.

In your case the relevant JsonPath expression will be as simple as:

```
$.ConnectionToken
```

Demo (assumes "JsonPath Tester" more of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using 2 JSON Extractor Post Processor. Add both JSON Extractor PostProcessor as a child of your HTTP Request.

1. To extract ConnectionID: use the following expression

> $.ConnectionId

2. To extract ConnectionToken : use the following expression

> $.ConnectionToken

3. Afterwards you can access ID and Token from variable `${ID} and ${Token}` respectively

[image]
[image]